# Sharing video on facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, iframe, meta-tags

When I share this link

http://common.tv2.dk/mpx/?guid=qYkgXNIgc_vsksCsdqFYlBP7Cv1W_XGz

on facebook it looks okay. But if I try to start the video I get this error

```
Refused to display 'https://attachment.fbsbx.com/external_iframe.php#channel=u_jsonp_3_i&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.
```

When I inspect the dom, i can see it's trying to iframe in

https://attachment.fbsbx.com/external_iframe.php#channel=u_jsonp_3_i&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com

Looking at the response header for this call it has x-frame-options set to deny

So my question is, why does facebook try to iframe in a source that does not allow it, and what should I do to fix it?

Comment: File a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: It’s already been reported, https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/924869304289329 Next time, please go look through current bugs in the bugtracker before asking here.

Comment: They closed the issue, but it still not working. I have commented on the thread. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Issue now fixed. Try clearing browser cache if you are still seeing the problem. Worked for me.